# Returning two array indices in an array for a given value

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms

Give an algorithm that takes as input an array A sorted in non-decreasing order, and a value x, and that returns two indices (F and L) into A, where A[F] is the first value equal to x and A[L] is the last value equal to x. Your algorithm should run as fast as possible in the worst case. State the worst case running
time of your algorithm.

A O(n) algorithm is very easy for this. A for loop running on the input array could easily find F,L. I think for sure there is a better algorithm. I am thinking of modifying binary search to search for the same value repetitively. I think O(logn) might not be possible, but something like $O(log ^2 n)$ might be. I am unable to come up with a precise algorithm that achieves something like this running time.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, [bisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)'ll maximize the information gained from each check.  If you do any sort of check other than bisection, then in the worst-case, the sought element'll be on the larger section of the selected divide.

The worst-case scenarios will occur whenever bisection has to happen $O\left(\log{n}\right)$ times to find the first/last indices of the selected value, `x`.  For example, if the array's all the same value, e.g. `A=[0,...,0]`, then bisection'll have to occur until the algorithm whittles it down to the first `0` at $i=0$, then a separate bisective search would have to go just as many times to find the last `0` at $i=n_{\mathrm{length}}-1$.

Both searches'll be $O\left(\log{n}\right)$.  But since two sequential $O\left(\log{n}\right)$ processes are still just $O\left(\log{n}\right)$, the overall algorithm's $O\left(\log{n}\right)$.

Comment: I don't think your overall analysis is correct.  You say the binary search in the worst case might happen $O\left(\log{n}\right)$  times. Each search takes $O\left(\log{n}\right)$  time.  Also you don't specify many details how your algorithm works. I assume like how I did, you do binary search till you don't find that element. I was thinking of a recursion algorithm which I am yet to do precisely though.

Comment: @T.Harish Sure, you could describe it as a recursive algorithm.  Just do a recursive bisective search for the specified input value, `x`.  Then once you find an index `i` at which `A[i]==x`, then you just need to find the first-and-last indices for the range over which `A[i]==x`.  So, just continue the bisective search (rather than restart it) since you already know the the current slice of `A` is bound by a value that's less-than-`x` on the left and greater-than-`x`- on the right.

Comment: @T.Harish Note that recursive algorithms and loops are basically two different formats for the same algorithm, so you can program this with loops or recursion; whatever's easiest for you.  Most folks find recursion to be conceptually simpler.  Recursion grows the stack, but for small problems like this, that shouldn't be a practical problem.  Personally I'd probably do this recursively unless it was performance-critical, in which case recasting it to a loop would be a hand-optimization.

Comment: @T.Harish BTW, this sounds like a homework problem, so I'm intentionally only pointing you in the right direction rather than writing out the actual code.  You're on the right track with the idea to modify a binary search.